# Moving websites to Github - what about email?

Tags: hosting

I'm thinking of moving about 5 websites over to be hosted on Github pages from a dedicated host. They will all be converted to static websites. The domain names will still be managed there, what are some options for email hosting cheaply or at all?

Answer (score 0):

I've always gone with [Google's G Suite](https://gsuite.google.com/pricing.html#choose-a-plan).

The basic plan gives 30GB of storage, and costs $5/User/Month

The business plan gives Unlimited storage, a few more features, and costs $10/User/Month

There's also an enterprise plan, but I don't think you'd need it.

Comment: Thanks is that $5 each user on a domain?

Comment: I believe so. I'd double check on their website though, just to be sure.